# "For some" vs. "for all" in set builder notation

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a set of nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where for each vector, its nonzero elements have the same magnitude. For example, when $n = 4$, $(1, 0, 1, 0)$ and $(-3, 3, 0, 3)$ are in this set, while $(1, 2, 3, 2)$ and $(0, 0, 0, 0)$ are not.

The formal notation I came up for it is
$$
\{
  x \in \mathbb{R}^n
  \mid
  \text{\(x \ne 0\) and \(x_i \in \{0, k, -k\}\) for some \(k \in \mathbb{R}\)}
\},
$$
but I'm not sure if the "for some $k$" part is correct. Should it be "for all $k$" instead?

Comment: If $x_i \in \{0,k,-k\}$ for all $k$, then $x_i \in \{0,1,-1\} \cap \{0,2,-2\} \cap \cdots$, which means $x_i = 0$.

Comment: @azifmedrano So it seems my current notation is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say "$x_i\in \{0,k,-k\}$ for all $k\in \Bbb R$" then you say that $x_i$ belongs to $every$ $\{0,k,-k\}$, which is not possible unless $x_i=0.$ And you do not want that for $every$ $i$.

What you wrote is OK but could be mis-interpreted.

You could also write $\{x\in \Bbb R^n: x\ne 0\land \exists k\in \Bbb R \,\forall i\, (x_i\in \{0,k,-k\})\}.$

If you want to be annoyingly rigorous but still right, you could write $\cup_{k\in \Bbb R}(\{0,k,-k\}^n) \setminus \{0\}^n.$

Comment: I was re-writing the 2nd line when the Acceptance mark appeared. A computer  might mis-interpret what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you. "A computer might mis-interpret what you wrote" -- could you explain? Is it simply because it is using English, or is it because the expression is actually ambiguous even for a human? (Not that it really matters in my specific case as it's just for a homework, but I'm still curious.)

Comment: English is slippery. In what you wrote, it does not say that for $x$ in the set, it  must be the same $k$ for all $i$. A human would infer that you meant that.

Comment: I see. I guess rewording it as "there exists some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_i\in\{0,k,-k\}$ for all $i$" is better.